# Permissions for Auto-Save files

Tags: auto-save, permissions

I use the configuration to store auto-save files in `/tmp`:

```lisp
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```

Emacs seems to create the auto-save-files with the actual permissions of the file changed. I would like to change the umask for auto-save files to 700. How to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in init.el to configure the default permissions of all newly created files:

```
(set-default-file-modes ?\700)
```

To apply this only to auto-save files I think you could use [around advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-Combinators.html) on `make-auto-save-file-name` combined with `default-file-modes` to first store old default permissions, then set new ones, then run the advised function, and finally reset the old default permissions.